# On Motorola G2 when on speaker call and power button ends call feature turned on. Cannot go to screen without ending the call

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, motorola

On Motorola G version 2.
 When:
1. On call using speaker, and
2. Power button ends call feature on.

I am unable to go back to screen in any condition. I have tried:
1.Using  volume keys.
2.Moving phone in every angle, i.e. proximity doesn't seem to work.